# Issues with compare time differences to 0 and return T/F

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation

I have date data like the following:

```
date = {"2008-05-13", "2008-05-14", "2008-05-15", "2008-05-16", "2008-05-19", "2008-05-20", "2008-05-21", "2008-05-22", "2008-05-23", "2008-11-17"}
```

and I want to compare the date each day's difference from `2008-05-13` is 0 or not.

and I have used the following code: `2008-05-13` stored in `dates[1,4]` (another data)

```
(dates[1,4] - date)) != (dates[1,4] - dates[1,4])
```

but this condition always returns me true and I do not know why this is happening. And the following is another code that I have tried and it is also always true.

```
 (dates[1,4] - date)) != 0
```

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can tell me what is going on.

Comment: Firstly you need to wrap in `c(...)`, not `{...}` in R. Secondly, you have to convert to Date class with `date <- as.Date(date)`. Then you can use subtraction/`difftime` effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set your dates as dates with the `as.Date` function. Moreover, you define a vector in R with `c()`. Use this instead:

```
 date  <- as.Date("2008-05-13")
 dates <- as.Date(c("2008-05-13", "2008-05-14" ,"2008-05-15" ,"2008-05-16" ,"2008-05-19" ,"2008-05-20" ,"2008-05-21", "2008-05-22", "2008-05-23", "2008-11-17"))

dates - date != 0
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Since you only using dates based on `YYYY-MM-DD` and not `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`, you could also compare just characters without converting it to dates:

```
date  <- "2008-05-13"
dates <- c("2008-05-13", "2008-05-14" ,"2008-05-15" ,"2008-05-16" ,"2008-05-19" ,"2008-05-20" ,"2008-05-21", "2008-05-22", "2008-05-23", "2008-11-17")

dates != date 
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

However, you should use the second approach only if you are sure all dates have the same format as indicated by the comment of *alistaire*.

Comment: You should be careful with the second approach; dates can come in a lot of different formats, and if they don't match, it will break. Better to parse to the appropriate class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simply:

```
date =c("2008-05-13", "2008-05-14" ,"2008-05-15" ,"2008-05-16" ,"2008-05-19" ,"2008-05-20" ,"2008-05-21", "2008-05-22", "2008-05-23", "2008-11-17") 
as.Date(date) - as.Date('2008-05-13') == 0
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: In this specific example, you don't even necessarily require explicit conversion via `as.Date` (though it probably makes sense to!) `difftime(date, "2008-05-13") == 0`

Comment: but when I tried min(abs(as.Date(dates[1,4])- as.Date(sp$date))) == 0.. this still returns me T while sp$date is different 2008-05-13

Comment: assuming your sp$date contains a list of dates including 2008-05-13, the min of all the absolute differences will be zero and the expression will evaluate to T, is not it expected?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called difftime in R. Thats the easiest way you can do it.

```
> date = as.Date(c("2008-05-13", "2008-05-14" ,"2008-05-15" ,"2008-05-16" ,"2008-05-19" ,"2008-05-20" ,"2008-05-21", "2008-05-22", "2008-05-23", "2008-11-17"))
> compare <- as.Date("2008-05-13")
> 
> x <- difftime(date, compare,units = "days")
> x
Time differences in days
[1]   0   1   2   3   6   7   8   9  10 188
```